# Why h:panelGroup with dynamic id launch java.lang.NullPointerException (JSF)?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am working with JSF 2.2 and I would like to have `h:panelGroup` in a `h:column` but the page doesn't load. The xhtml indicates the following exception:

`/view/index.xhtml @120,124 id="pgEliminarFuncion#{estrategiaBean.atributoString(atributo)}" /view/strat.xhtml @120,124 id="pgEliminarFuncion#{estrategiaBean.atributoString(atributo)}": java.lang.NullPointerException`.

I have the following xhtml code (where everything works out fine):

```
<h:dataTable value="#{estrategiaBean.funcionesDeParte}" var="atributo">
    <h:column>
        #{estrategiaBean.atributoString(atributo)}
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

When I change the xhtml code to...

```
<h:dataTable value="#{estrategiaBean.funcionesDeParte}" var="atributo">
    <h:column>
        <h:panelGroup id="pgEliminarFuncion#{estrategiaBean.atributoString(atributo)}">
            hello!
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

... The page doesn't load.

How can I add correctly `h:panelGroup` to my first code?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to manually ensure uniqueness of IDs. JSF will already do that. Just use `<h:panelGroup id="pgEliminarFuncion">`